# How to refactor to cleaner version of maintaing states of the widget

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, refactoring, state

**Backstory**

I inherited a bunch of code that I'd like to refactor. It is a UI application written in javascript.

**Current state:**

We have main application which consist of several UI components. And each component  has entry fields, textboxes, menus, etc), like "ticket", "customer information", etc. Based on input, where the application was called from, who is the user, we enable/disable, hide, show, change titles.

Unfortunately, the app grew to the point where it is really hard to scale, add new features. Main the driver (application code) calls set/unset functions of the respective components. So a lot of the stuff look like this

Main app unit

```
function1() {
   **call_function2()**
   component1.setX(true);
   component1.setY(true);
   component2.setX(false);
}

call_function2() { 
       // it may repeat some of the code function1 called 
}
```

and we have a lot of this in the main union.

I am cleaning this mess. What is the best way to maintain the state of widgets?
Please let me know if you need me to clarify.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your code looks like you are accessing your view code directly from functions which as you correctly pointed is a bad idea. If you application is lot of GUI stuff then I would suggest you go with MVVM approach. 
It would keep your view, binding and functionality completely separately. In future if you want to change the GUI, you can do it without touching any other classes. 
Well I am not from JS background, but this is what my .Net exp says.